# How to increment a Resource?

Tags: java, rdf, ontology, jena, owl

I have a function that adds instances (and their properties values) of class `Person` in a RDF file when I click on the Add button. I can add the first instance, but when I try to add the second, it replaces the first instance by the second.

I think it is because I do not increment `Resource P1 = model.createResource(personURI+"Name")`, after adding the first instance.

How can I increment a `Resource` in java from `P1` to `P2` to `P3`, etc?

```
public class ActionAjoutPersonne implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {

        Onto f = new Onto();

        Resource p1 = f.model.createResource(f.uriBase+tabTF[0].getText());


        p1.addProperty(f.aPourPrenom, tabTF[0].getText());         
        p1.addProperty(f.aPourNom, tabTF[1].getText());         
        p1.addProperty(f.aDateNaiss, tabTF[2].getText()); 

        if (tabTF[3].getText().equals("F"))
        {
            p1.addProperty(f.aGenre, tabTF[3].getText()); 
            p1.addProperty(RDF.type, f.femme);
        }
        else if (tabTF[3].getText().equals("H"))
        {
            p1.addProperty(f.aGenre, tabTF[3].getText());    
            p1.addProperty(RDF.type, f.homme);
        }

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        f.model.write(sw, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
        String owlCode = sw.toString();
        File file = new File("d:/teste20.rdf");
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            fw.write(owlCode);
            fw.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            fnfe.printStackTrace();} 
        catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you create several resources with the same URL. Could you provide complete code fragment?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I edited my post and added the code for Button Add. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using Jena?

The `createResource(uri)` method will overwrite an existing resource if you call it again with the same URI argument.

So you have to make sure to assign a different URI for each person.

You can achieve this using some sort of auto-incrementing counter, or by making the person's name a part of the URI (`using URLEncoder.encode(name, "utf-8")` for example).

Comment: Hi cygri. Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm using Jena. I edited my post and added my code fragment for Button Add. How can I use URLEncoder? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear what your precise end goal here is, A.R., but I can see two possibilities:

- you want a series of files on disk, with different file names, each containing the RDF fragment from one user's form
- you want one file on disk, but which contains multiple RDF subjects, each one representing a different user's form details

In the first case, you would need to change the output file each time. Currently you have:

```
File file = new File("d:/teste20.rdf");
```

so the file name is fixed to 'teste20.rdf'. You would have to change that to use a different file name each time. There are various ways to achieve that: one way would be to have a `private static int` field on your class which you increment each time:

```
File file = new File("d:/teste_" + fileCounter++ + ".rdf");
```

There are other ways, which you can see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825678/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-unique-and-short-file-name-in-java).

If, however, you want the second case: multiple RDF resources in one file, then it's a little hard to diagnose the problem without seeing more of the code. However, if the model in:

```
Resource p1 = f.model.createResource(...)
```

is not the same model each time (I can't tell from your code how that model is being created), the each time the listener runs, you create a model containing only the new data from the user's form, and then write that out in place. In that case, you have two choices: either don't keep creating a new model every time (but that means the model will eventually get quite large, and would also reset every time your application restarts), or read the existing contents of `d:/teste20.rdf` *before* you write out the contents of the model (not tested, but should work):

```
    File file = new File("d:/teste20.rdf");
    f.model.read( new FileReader( file ) );
    f.model.write( new FileWriter( file ), "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
```

If you're not creating a new model each time, an assuming that the expression `f.uriBase+tabTF[0].getText()` gives you a unique URI string for each user (otherwise the problem is non-unique subject URI's, as Richard suggested), then we would need to see more of the code to get to the root cause.

Answer (score -2):

You are just rewriting the file four times. I suggest you to use some structured programming practices to avoid this kind of mistakes in the future.

Comment: Hi CheatEx, I removed the loop "For". but it still overwrite the existing instance in RDF File.

Comment: This kind of answer is anything but helpful. Instead of suggesting someone to "use some structured programming practices" you should tell where the error is and how to fix or improve the code. This kind of answer just scares people off and makes them not to post more questions in SO (-1)

Comment: @msalvadores I pointed the error and gave a piece of advice. Just can't do anything more.

Comment: The second sentence in your answer can be avoided or articulated in a manner that is linked to the question so to be constructive. That is my point.