# Saving to a folder

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

I'm writing an application that is writing to a file. I'm wondering if it's possible to write to a folder, without specifying a file name.  The way I have it set up now, my program will overwrite the previous saved file. I'm looking to have it add to the folder rather than replace.

Here's the line in question:

```
File testFile = new File("C:/TargetFolder/testFile.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to write to a file without assigning a file name. However, if you don't want to chose a file name you can have your system generate a random one. For example look at these options: [What is the best way to generate a unique and short file name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825678/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-unique-and-short-file-name-in-java).

Another option would be to add numbers to your file name like: `test01.png, test02.png` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do the unique file in the folder logic yourself and you don't care much about the exact name, you might use:

```
java.io.File.createTempFile("testFile", ".png", new File("C:/TargetFolder"));
```