# Different File name for every new recorded sound

Tags: android, filenames

I am working on sound recording app and I have a small problem.
I want recorded files to be saved and it works fine, except there is a problem with names.
I have this code:

```
int num = 0;
File FolderCreator = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/My Recored Songs/Pads/");
File FileCreator = new File(FolderCreator, "My Record.mp3");
```

And then

```
if (FileCreator.exists()) {
    num++;
    FileCreator = new File(FolderCreator, "My Record "
            + num +".mp3");
}
```

And it works. But the problem is, if I leave app and start it again it will start counting from 1 and overwrite previous files.
How can I prevent that?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825678/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-unique-and-short-file-name-in-java

Comment: Or if you want to stick with your existing pattern and have the names to be an incrementing count that is consistent across sessions, use something like SharedPreferences to track the last one used.  Or scan the directory where you keep them and find the last one in existence and increment from there.

Comment: Well of course, SharedPreferences. I completely forgot about that. And Yeah I'd prefer to stick to my pattern. I've already had TimeStamp names and its confusing. Plus its too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the number of existing files in the folder and set num to equal that.

```
int num = 0;
File FolderCreator = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/My Recored Songs/Pads/");
...

File[] listOfFiles = FolderCreator.listFiles();
num = listOfFiles.length;

....
```

Comment: Shared Preferences is a cleaner way, for sure (since you're storing on the SD Card, the files are exposed to the user and could be moved/deleted, which would screw up the counting), but figured this - as a pure Java-esque impementation - needed to be said.

Comment: I like the idea; the only weird thing would be if a file gets deleted out of sequence. The length would be one value, but that file could already exist!

Comment: @ChrisForrence exactly.. .see comment above.

Comment: Could also (over)write the total save count to a text file over time in order to mitigate that (??), but easier to just use SharedPrefs at that point...

Comment: Yes indeed, if user wants to delete some recorded file it could mess up the count. But I don't know which answer to choose. This method works, other answers are copy of ChrisForrence's answer or not what I'm looking for. @ChrisForrence can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @SlimC just give me an upvote and I'm happy. My answer will work, but like the timestamp one, it's not the best answer.

Comment: I already did. I wanted to accept your answer but then you commented :P

Comment: Haha... oops! I'd say SpaceMonkey's answer is the closest.

Comment: @SlimC. While I appreciate the thought, I think you meant Chris Stratton (the guy who had commented on your question)

Comment: @ChrisForrence Oh yeah, sorry my bad. I just glanced over the names :D

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Date` class along with `Time`.

```
new File("MyRecord-ddMMyyhhmmss.mp3");
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to store the Value of "num" into SharedPreferences and increment it when you save a sound file.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html