# When viewing a downloaded PDF generated by Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have created a PDF file using Itext API in java and dowloaded. When i try to view it it gives me

[image]

When i try to insert any image i get this error. If there is no image in my PDF it opens fine. And also if i write the pdf to my local system then also it works fine.

I am getting the issue only when the pdf contains image and it is downloaded.

Below is the code i used for setting image in the pdf

```
Document doc = new Document();
File file = new File(new Random().nextInt(10000)+"_orders.pdf");
PdfWriter docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(file));
doc.open();
Image companyLogo = Image.getInstance("http://www.quicklyjava.com/wp-content/themes/hybrid-news/images/sitelogo.png");
companyLogo.setAbsolutePosition(20, 720);
companyLogo.scalePercent(50);
doc.add(companyLogo);
doc.close();
return file;
```

Can any one help me to fix this.

Adding some Info: When downloaded opens fine in the browser. Issue when opened in Adobe reader.

Comment: can you open it in another programe like photoshop,web browser or another pdf viewer

Comment: "*When downloaded opens fine in the browser. Issue when opened in Adobe reader.*" - Do you open in Adobe Reader by first downloading the PDF to your file system and opening it from there? Or do you mean the Adobe Reader browser plugin? In the former case it should be easy for you to share the PDF Adobe Reader has issues with; thus, please do so! In the latter case you have to consider that the plugin might open a second request for that file and this second request might cause you issues.

Answer (score 4):

## Part 1: don't fetch an Image from an URL

You say that your code works on your local machine. That's great: you have established that the problem isn't related to iText, hence the problem must be caused by something else.

Looking at your code sample, the most likely culprit is `http://www.quicklyjava.com/wp-content/themes/hybrid-news/images/sitelogo.png`.

Your image is stored on an external site.

It's never a good idea to fetch images from a web site using the `Image` class in general, because the `Image` class attempts to read the bytes of an image a couple of times. At least once to read the first bytes in order to detect the type of image (this will determine which image class iText needs to use); at least once to load all the bytes in a specific image class.

The fact that your code works on your local machine and not on your server, leads to believe that your local machine has access to that site, whereas restrictions may be in place on your server. Maybe your server isn't allowed to access the web site where your image resides. In that case, an exception is thrown and that could lead to a damaged PDF.

Or maybe only part of the image is downloaded by the specific image class that has to deal with the PNG file.

How to solve this?

Either put your logo in your jar and load the logo from that jar. Or put the logo on the file system on the server and read it from the file system. Or load the logo in a `byte[]` first, check if that byte array actually contains a valid image, and if not, throw an exception and inform the user that something went wrong.

## Part 2: a standalone example isn't the same as a server example

In a comment, you write: *When i run my code through main method and write the PDF in some location then everything works fine. But when i try to download the file using servlet by running my code in tomcat. It gives me the error.*

As mkl wrote in his reply to this comment, you should update your question. The sample code in your question looks as if you are creating a file on disk. This isn't custom when writing a web application. In a web context, you usually generate a PDF in memory and then serve it to the browser as explained in the answer to the question [How can I serve a PDF to a browser without storing a file on the server side?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-serve-pdf-browser-without-storing-file-server-side)

Note that this answer provides a short code sample and a long code sample. Maybe you have experimented with the short code sample and maybe you've experienced a problem with it because although the code in the short sample should work, not all browsers accept it. The long version works around some known browser issues:

```
public class PdfServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // Get the text that will be added to the PDF
            String text = request.getParameter("text");
            if (text == null || text.trim().length() == 0) {
                 text = "You didn't enter any text.";
            }
            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
            // step 3
            document.open();
            // step 4
            document.add(new Paragraph(String.format(
                "You have submitted the following text using the %s method:",
                request.getMethod())));
            document.add(new Paragraph(text));
            // step 5
            document.close();

            // setting some response headers
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            // setting the content type
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            // the contentlength
            response.setContentLength(baos.size());
            // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            baos.writeTo(os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
        catch(DocumentException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you'll have to provide more info.

## Part 3: the file name you create is not unique!

I don't know why you're creating a file on when it's your intention to serve the PDF to a browser, but if it's a deliberate choice, I would use this:

```
File file = new File(new Random().nextInt(10000)+"_orders.pdf");
```

By using `nextInt()`, I think it's theoretically possible that two different users are attributed the same number simultaneously. This will cause problems. If you want to create a unique file name, then please don't use `Random`, but create a unique file name as described in the question [What is the best way to generate a unique and short file name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825678/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-unique-and-short-file-name-in-java)

```
File file = File.createTempFile("order", ".pdf", new File("/user/vijay"));
```

## Part 4: use a recent iText version

I don't really understand what you mean when you write *when downloaded opens normally in browser. but having issue when opened in Adobe reader.* It sounds as if the PDF has a flaw that is ignored by some PDF viewers (like pdf.js in Firefox, Chrome PDF Viewer in Chrome, Preview in Safari,...) but that causes an error message in Adobe Reader. Are you by any chance using an ancient iText version? Which iText version did you use?

Comment: When i run my code through main method and write the PDF in some location then everything works fine. But when i try to download the file using servlet by running my code in tomcat. It gives me the error. Further Info : when downloaded opens normally in browser. but having issue when opened in Adobe reader.

Comment: @VijayRahul "*But when i try to download the file using servlet by running my code in tomcat.*" - Thus, your error seems to be related to how you return the PDF from the servlet. You had better update your question to focus on this detail, in particular show your code returning the PDF to the caller.