# Limit length of filename from Java 7's Files.createTempFile

Tags: java, filenames

Is there a way to limit the filename (basename) length of Java 7's `java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Path dir, String prefix, String suffix, FileAttribute<?>... attributes)` call?

On my system, it creates a file with `<prefix><long_integer><suffix>`, e.g. with `dir="", prefix="tmp-", suffix=".txt"` I get a filename of:
`tmp-661852960452024998.txt`.

I would like to limit length of the generated unique long integer (e.g. `661852960452024998` in my example, say to 4 or 8 chars, such that the result would be something like: `tmp-6618.txt` for limit of 4 chars or `tmp-66185296.txt` for limit of 8 chars.

Comment: Why? It's a *temporary* file, with temporary content, and file will be deleted (soon). It's in the nature of **temporary**. No one should care what the file name is.

Comment: To give some kind of answer: no, you can't do this. Looking at the source code for Java 10 there is no way to customize how long the randomly generated number will be.

Comment: In my use case, it is actually not a temporary file, I want to generate a unique file with a predefined prefix and suffix in my specified directory.

Comment: Then you should create your own method for it. The `long` number is probably used to minimize the possibility of a collision when creating lots of temp files.

Comment: I think also that you have to implement it by yourself. This question seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825678/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-unique-and-short-file-name-in-java. I guess if you just want shorter file names just incrementing a sequence number would be fine and is the simplest approach.