# generate files with unique names and write data into them

Tags: java, file-io

I want to write data fetched from a database table every time to new text files with different names.

I use `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` to make the filename unique and create the corresponding new txt file in the required directory:

```
String path = "/home/username/Documents/Netbeans Projects/cashbackEngine/Reports";

Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm");


SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(currentTime);
String reportFileName2 = "ICC_Cashback_Report_SS_$1$.txt".replace("$1$", sdf.format(currentTime));

String reportFilePath2 = path + "/" + reportFileName2;

File file = new File(reportFilePath2);
writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

Then I iterate over the dataset and write the data to the file by using `writer.write();`

Is there any other simple way to do this... or any inbuilt string builder method in Java to automatically generates the new file names with constant prefix and unique suffix numbers.

I don't want to use a timestamp to distinguish it from others 
and every time new data will get added to the newly generated text file whenever the Java code is executed...

Comment: I'm unsure what it is you want.  `I don't want date to be at the end of the txt file to distinguish it from others` - what do you want to differentiate between files then?  Just an incremented value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple counter as a file prefix. You'd have to persist the current state of the counter between different runs of the program, though, e.g. also in the database. Here's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825678/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-unique-and-short-file-name-in-java) dealing with the same issue and answers containing your current approach and others.